# Why all posts are marked as community wiki?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

On the following page:

[Getting the source directory of a Bash script from within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)

it seems that all posts are marked as community wiki which is kind of weird.

Why is that? It is a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this is not a bug.

This has 41 non deleted answers (52 answers including deleted ones).

It [used to be the case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/11741/39) that questions with many answers (more than 30 on Stackoverflow) were auto converted.